# How to use liScroll JQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I use **JavaScript** to display bulk on news I did my code well and everything is OK but I need to make  the news display from Left to Right. I use JQuery file liScroll .

**aspx page**

```
 <ul id="ticker02" >
                        <asp:DataList ID="DLQ" runat="server" RepeatColumns="10" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li><span>...</span><a href='<%#Eval("Art_ID","NewsDetailsPage.aspx?ID="+ Eval("Art_ID"))%>'>
                                    <%# Eval("Title")%></a></li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
                    </ul>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("ul#ticker02").liScroll({ travelocity: 0.05 });

    });
</script>
```

**JQuery file :**

```
jQuery.fn.liScroll = function (settings) {
settings = jQuery.extend({
    travelocity: 0.20
}, settings);
return this.each(function () {
    var $strip = jQuery(this);
    $strip.addClass("newsticker")
    var stripWidth = 1;
    $strip.find("li").each(function (i) {
        stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).outerWidth(true); // thanks to Michael Haszprunar and Fabien Volpi
    });
    var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
    var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");
    var containerWidth = $strip.parent().parent().width();  //a.k.a. 'mask' width   
    $strip.width(stripWidth);
    var totalTravel = stripWidth + containerWidth;
    var defTiming = totalTravel / settings.travelocity; // thanks to Scott Waye     
    function scrollnews(spazio, tempo) {
        $strip.animate({ left: '-=' + spazio }, tempo, "linear", function () { $strip.css("left", containerWidth); scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming); });
    }
    scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
    $strip.hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).stop();
    },
    function () {
        var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
        var residualSpace = offset.left + stripWidth;
        var residualTime = residualSpace / settings.travelocity;
        scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<li class="classname">`

Then

Use this :

```
jQuery.fn.liScroll = function (settings) {
settings = jQuery.extend({
    travelocity: 0.20
}, settings);
return this.each(function () {
    var $strip = jQuery(this);
    $strip.addClass("newsticker")
    var stripWidth = 1;      
    $strip.find('.classname').each(function (i) { <-- Change Here
        stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).outerWidth(true); // thanks to Michael Haszprunar and Fabien Volpi
    });
    var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
    var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");
    var containerWidth = $strip.parent().parent().width();  //a.k.a. 'mask' width   
    $strip.width(stripWidth);
    var totalTravel = stripWidth + containerWidth;
    var defTiming = totalTravel / settings.travelocity; // thanks to Scott Waye     
    function scrollnews(spazio, tempo) {
        $strip.animate({ left: '-=' + spazio }, tempo, "linear", function () { $strip.css("left", containerWidth); scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming); });
    }
    scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
    $strip.hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).stop();
    },
    function () {
        var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
        var residualSpace = offset.left + stripWidth;
        var residualTime = residualSpace / settings.travelocity;
        scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
    });
});
```

Comment: what classname contain ?

Comment: any name that you need to give for the class li and the same name in javascript to call  that li tag